# Create a dynamic JQuery to disable a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, servlets

I am working with Servlet and JSP. I have a JSP form in which I have a drop down list which is getting generated dynamically so as of now I have three options in the drop down list.

*HTML CODE*--

```
<form id='form' method='post' action='/test/'>
<select id="type" name="typeOne">

<optgroup id="first" name="First" label="FirstDiv">
    <option value="value1" id="001">valuee1 count</option>
    <option value="value2" id="002">value2</option>
    <option value="value3" id="003">value3
    </option>
</optgroup>
</select>
</form>
```

Now I need to disable few of the options in my above drop down list using jquery. Below is my jquery in which I am disabling the `001` and `002` options but I have hardcoded the id's in my below jquery -

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#type option[id='001']").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#type option[id='002']").prop("disabled", true);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Below is my servlet from which I am passing a list which will have all my id's which I want to disable in my drop down list.

```
List<String> storeTest = new ArrayList<String>();
storeTest.add("001");
storeTest.add("002");

req.setAttribute("store", storeTest);
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Now my question is - how do I iterate `store` list in the jquery and disable `001` and `002` options in the drop down list?

Comment: first you need to get the data on client side (i.e. to your jQuery) for that either you need to make another ajax call to servlet and return data in parsable format or you pass the data along with main page in some hidden part of page and read it from jQuery and process it

Comment: OP is already passing the store list in a request attribute I guess.

Comment: Yes, it is already passing the value. I need to know how can I use that value from the list in my jsp and further iterate to create a disable jquery statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare your selectors in `Servlet` , then inject it in `JSP` :

### MyServlet.java

```
List<String> storeTest = new ArrayList<String>();
storeTest.add("001");
storeTest.add("002");
// If you have Java8 : use Lamda list.stream().map(e->'#'+e)
req.setAttribute("store",StringUtils.join(mapForId(storeTest).toArray(),",")); 

this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/myPage.jsp" ).forward( req, response );
```

then in your jsp , adding an expression as  following:

## myPage.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//....
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(function () {
            jQuery(<%=request.getAttribute("store") %>).prop("disabled", true);
            
        });
    });

</script>
```

Known that **mapForId** is another method in Servlet :

```
List<String> mapForId(List l){
  List<String> newArr=new ArrayList<String>();
  for(String attr : l){
      newArr.add("option#"+attr);
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you عبد النور التومي, for the reply, I am using java 6 not java 8? how to do it in Java 6?

Comment: UPDATED! if there is a pb of casting object , i hope that u can deal with. And if `jQuery(<%=request.getAttribute("store") %>)` does not work , try adding *' '* : `jQuery('<%=request.getAttribute("store") %>')`

Comment: I am getting error on `.join(","));` do I have to add any maven dependency or create any method?? error is - `cannot resolve method join()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55302/discussion-between----and-akiiddweeber).

Comment: If I `alert` I get `null` as value not `001` and `002` :( any help would be great?

Comment: Resolved, the mapForId() method was appending option# in front of the id selector. thanks